How does the early first version of M68K emulator work?
Context: I'm fascinated by Rosetta 2 so I Googled a bit and reached the wiki page. It talked about the M68K emulator (embedded in ROM), and the related wiki page says:

Early versions emulated it by decoding each instruction and immediately carrying out a series of equivalent PowerPC instructions.


Dynamic recompilation works by "recompiling" common sections of the code into faster, PowerPC-native, sequences that were locally cached.

I don't know much about emulators, but this doesn't look like a software emulation, because it spits out PowerPC instructions which should be executed natively.
What I don't get is, how does the program execute the generated native code? I have done a couple of simple low level programming projects (emulation and interpreter), but AFAIK I don't know how to generate code in memory (I guess the code must reside in memory?) and then "jump" to it. How do you achieve this in assembly or C (Obj-C)?
To simplify things, let's stick to the "read 1 instruction -> translate to PowerPC instruction(s) -> execute them -> read next instruction" version of the M68K emulator. How does everything work underneath?
Here is my guess:

User launches a 68K application (called "app")

System 7.x recognizes that this is a 68K app so launches the M68K emulator (called "emu")

"emu" reads into the binary executable file, fetches the next instruction

"emu" generates a bunch of PowerPC instructions

Power PC somehow executes these instructions

Go back to step 3


I can understand steps 1-3 & 6 but not 4-5, how does the "emu" manipulate the PC (program counter) of the Power PC CPU in real time to run the generated code? Where do they reside? Does the emulator basically put each PowerPC instruction (with parametrization) into a label, and jump to different labels?

Don't have time to write a full answer - but your step 2 is essentially the same as steps 4&5.  Instructions are placed in memory and executed.  The main difference is whether the instruction stream was sitting in a disk file (step 2: the 'emu' program) or is being made up on-the-fly.

The question body seems to ask about the later (compiling) version, while the title seems to ask about the earlier (interpreting) version. Mind to clarify/adjust that?

Recompilation is also used in other tools like Valgrind or QEMU. The unit of compilation is what is called a basic block in compiler theory. Usually there's a cache for compiled code.

I think you might be underestimating the amount of 68k code still being used by the OS if you think the 68k emulator ever wasn't already resident. That was not a decade in which Apple had much OS development expertise, or an OS built with adaptability in mind.

There's no real rocket science involved in this.
Instructions are just bytes with specific values. For an emulator, they're just data stored in memory like any other data.
If you're writing your emulator in assembly language, you just jump to the address of the memory where you wrote the data. If (as I'd expect here) your emulator is written in something like C or C++, you cast the address of the memory to a function type, and then call that function.
There is one other not-so-minor point to deal with: when you allocate memory from the OS, it's normally going to be marked to allow reading and writing but not execution. To execute it successfully, you'll typically need to ask the OS to set the right bits in the page protection bits to allow execution of it.
After that, it becomes largely a question of optimizing things so they work reasonably well. Just for example, there's a little ovherhead (a couple of instructions) to start executing code you generated, and to return to the emulator. You normally don't want to add that overhead to every instruction. Instead, you'd normally want to translate a fairly large number of 68K instructions, then execute them all as a group, so the overhead is amortized over enough instructions that it doesn't contribute much to execution time.
std::vector<char> ppc_instructions;
std::vector<short> m68K_instructions;

for (size_t i=0; i<input_size; i++) {
    ppc_instructions.push_back(translation(m68k_instructions[i]));
}
allow_execution(ppc_instructions);
ppc_instructions.push_back(RETURN_INSTRUCTION);

void (*ptr)() = ppc_instructions;
ptr();

That does oversimplify some parts of the job quite a bit. For example, the 68K used variable length instructions, so you don't know how long an instruction will be until you've at least started to decode it. So the loop to decode them won't be a simple for loop to just walk through the data in fixed increments--rather, as you decode instructions, you'll update the current input position based on the length of each instruction.
But it does give kind of the general flavor of it, at a very high level.

Other complication: Not losing control on branch/call instructions (especially if doing "one instruction at a time").  I'd probably choose to just emulate those.

@dave: I doubt that would work out well. You typically have quite a few tight loops for things like memset, and strcpy. Emulating the jump for cases like that would impose a lot of overhead.

Thanks. Just to clarify a bit using an example. Assuming I see a 68K instruction, say (could be illegal) "MOV R1, 6", I'd prepare a table of function pointers, and then call say mov(). My original question is better presented as: in my C++ emulator, all registers are locations in memory, not hardware ones, so essentially mov() just puts 6 into reg[R6], is the M68K emulator doing the same thing, but written in assembly, so it can directly sets a register to the same value if it sees fit? @JerryCoffin

@NicholasHumphrey: It's probably doing more or less the same thing (but I'd emphasize one of the final points: it's almost certainly going to compile a number of instructions, so it's unlikely to have a pointer to a function that just does a single mov).

There's also the point that a lot of software would not need that much performance, so the first versions of the emulator could be useful for office applications, tax and accounting,... while later would start to be useful for games, image manipulation, multimedia,...

@JerryCoffin - sure, but that's why "one instruction at a time" (as mentioned in the question) is likely not a good design choice.

@NicholasHumphrey The M68k has 16 registers and the Power PC has 32 registers so if it's written in assembly you could (yo dawg) use your registers for registers.

Thanks folks, I think I'm done for the question.


how does the "emu" manipulates the PC (program counter) of the Power PC CPU in realtime to run the generated code?

By Jumping there? No, serious, it's simply a jump or call instruction. Which one depends on how the generated code ends, by a return or another jump (*1). C is pretty much prepared to use the call version by treating the pointer to the generated code as function pointer like this(*2):
(*codeptr)()

Where do they reside?

In Memory of course? The generated code gets placed in a memory section the emulator allocates for such. After all, code is nothing but data (*3). C code to do so is essentially string handling, or rather buffer handling (*4) as we need to include Null-bytes. Essentially something like
char CodeBuf[] = malloc(100); // 100 Bytes for our code snippet

CodeBuf[0] = <Instruction Byte 1>;
CodeBuf[1] = ...;
...
CodeBuf[n] = ...;
CodeBuf[n+1] = <opcode for return>;

Well, very essential. In reality it would be rather predefined code sections which get duplicated via memcpy() into the code buffer. For example a MOV D1,D3 would be a some memory load and store (DRegs[1] = DRegs[3]) as the 68k emulation will hold all 68k registers in memory.

Does the emulator basically put each PowerPC instruction (with parametrization) into a label, and jump to different labels?

No, no, no, but yes.

No, the Emulator will not put each 68k instruction into a function of it's own. Doing so would not really speed up execution, in fact it may rather slow it even further. To generate code, the program needs to analyse what the instruction does, so it cold perform it right away saving all translation and generation.

No, it's (almost) never just one (68k) instruction, but always a sequence, a continuous stream of as many instructions as possible into a single code section. In the most simple case that would be until a branch instruction is reached, as they can be tricky (*5). Such a section then, when called, will execute at maximum speed provided by the target CPU (*6).

No, labels are instructions to a compiler during program creation. When running all there is are memory addresses. Aka handling a heap of code sections and pointers thereon.

Yes, it puts each generated code section into a dedicated memory section, saves a pointer to it for later use and then jumps/calls that section once.


The important part is that saving of code and pointer. Its generating that code section once and using it many times without the generation overhead. In the end it's the age old Interpreter vs. Compiler story. Interpreters are great, but slow as they touch every instruction every time with all their overhead, while a compiler has overhead beforehand, but (hopefully) executing way faster after compilation.
That saving will be at minimum a list of 'known addresses' and generated code like this:
struct STab{
    char* Address;          // 68k start address of this code
    char* Next;             // Next 68k address after this segment 
    void (*CodePtr)(void);  // PowerPC code
} Sections[100];            // Array for 100 functions

...

// Fill a buffer from AktInstr using a Generate function essentially like above
Sections[n].Address = AktInstr;
Sections[n].CodePtr = (void*) Generate(&AktInstr);
Sections[n].Next    = AktInstr;
n++;

(Given, adding a bit more management than incrementing 'n' may be a good idea)

Here is my guess:

Almost, let's add a few further details

User launches a 68K application (called "app")

System 7.x recognizes that this is a 68K app so launches the M68K emulator (called "emu")

"emu" reads into the binary executable file,


Yes, plus setting up the (virtual) memory environment the app expects.

Emulator starts handling at program entry point

From here on it diverges form your list:

Checks instruction address - for a known address continue at step 15.

Fetches the that instruction

Checks if it's a translatable or a stop instruction (*7) - for stop instructions it continues at step 11

Generates one or more PowerPC instruction

Increments instruction fetch address

Continue at 5

(from 7 - stop instruction found)

Generate code to handle stop instruction

Close code segment with a final instruction (return or jump)

Note code segment in list of known addresses

(from 5 - known address)

Execute code (known) code segment (do a (*CodePtr)())

Continue at 5 with next 68k address (*8) noted in Sections[n].Next.


For simplicity a good number of additional cases, especially around stop instructions, have been left out for clarity. In fact, that - and data handling - is what occupied several very brilliant minds for quite some time.

No rocket science at all. In fact, generating code at runtime is a quite common technique, almost as old as computers are. A good portion of data base speed for ad hoc queries comes from compiling that SQL into code at runtime.
In a 1980s mainframe application we had several such special purpose compilers turning user input into machine code to speed up execution. If the task is to compare several parameters against hundrets or thousands of records (after selection by indices), the speed up by not having to parse each parameter each time can be extreme.
I guess it's somewhat of a forgotten art as most basic cases are handled by data base engines - and everything else by throwing hardware at it :))

*1 - Which in turn depends on the chaining strategy it uses. Both ways have their advantages. Subroutine is the most simple, while jumping may often generate faster code.
*2 - In C++ maybe a bit more complex using a reinterpret_cast, so lets stay with plain C.
*3 - Well, in an OS with execution protection that region may of course need to be marked as executable, but that's OS specific stuff.
*4 - Including of course all the hassles of doing so, like size checks, over run protection and so on.
*5 - Well, there's more, like management of external branch targets within such sections, but that's way beyond a simple overview.
*6 - Assuming a somewhat optimal translation of course.
*7 - Stop instructions are for example branches, OS calls or other items that need more 'intelligent' handling.
*8 - Make sure to not mix up 68k addresses, which are the ones all code refers to, with PPC addresses used do call the generated code. In fact, data handling in this environment adds another level of trickery :))

Also take a look at RetroBytes's Is this the most obscure Apple product?. It's about Macintosh Application Environment for Solaris and HP/UX, which the ancestor of the emulator they built into PPC versions of their system software.

Let's remember that the processor is PowerPC — there's no 68k processor in that environment.  So, the processor is always running PowerPC code, never 68k code.
There's software that has been programmed (as a PowerPC program, the emulator) to accomplish translation of 68k code (viewed by the processor as data) into PowerPC instruction sequences.  It does this in software but similar to how hardware would do this job using fetch, decode, execute, advance steps.
Basically, there is a giant switch/case statement where the code of each case handles the meaning/translation of each possible instruction encoding, and accomplishes the intent & effect of the 68k code in terms of an prearrangement of what that means.  This giant switch/case statement is embedded inside a fetch, next loop.
Importantly, there is a runtime model that is a prearranged mapping between the PowerPC processor resources and 68k processor resources.  This runtime model is part of the design of the emulator program.
For example, a given register on the 68k processor (say d0) maps to a given register on the PowerPC processor.  So, when the 68k code says something like add.l d0,d0 then using that prearranged mapping it is understood that the effect of doubling should take place on the appropriate PowerPC register mapping for the 68k's d0 and any effects on flags as well.  As emulation proceeds, the state of the 68k processor & program can be understood through this runtime model's mapping of 68k processor resources to PowerPC processor resources.
For the dynamic version, a capture of instruction sequences that accomplish the execution/execute steps bypasses the software emulator's loop of fetch, decode, next steps for subsequent emulation of the same 68k by executing only the captured execute steps of sequences of translated 68k code.  As with any software interpreter, the emulator's fetch, decode, next steps are a very costly (in terms of performance) part of the emulation, so bypassing those for frequently executed code sequences is a big win.

don't know much about emulators, but this doesn't look like a software emulation, because it spits out PowerPC instructions which should be executed natively.

That's what we call JIT'ing or dynamic compilation, which is a common approach to emulation/interpretation.

What I don't get is, how does the program executes the generated native code?

The processor is always running PowerPC code and nothing else.
So, for that early version of the emulator, a simple very large switch/case statement transfers control of the PowerPC processor to different case statement using the usual branch instructions found in switch/case statements.
For dynamically generating code to execute at runtime, an emulator captures code sequences that represent the execute part of the fetch, decode, execute, next steps that (a processor or) an emulator normally does.  This requires some extra memory to serve as a software cache of native (here PowerPC) instruction sequences.  These can be activated also by PowerPC branch instruction, usually those that might look like indirect jump or call.  All that is needed is an address to use with a jump instruction, since the emulator is already running as PowerPC code.
A compiled program stores a set of native processor instructions in a program file on disc.  That program file is loaded into memory (being loaded into memory gives each element of the program file a mapping to a memory address) and the native processor's program counter is set to the first instruction, which is an address within its loaded code.
JIT'ing isn't much different except that there's no program file on disc — instead the instructions come from the capture feature of the emulator.  There's more memory management involved, since the dynamic emulator is working in chunks, and doing some of the work that for compiled program would happen within the compiler.
In the compiled environment, many smaller chunks of translated code are consolidated into larger code sections, which removes much of the memory management that a JIT has to do.  A JIT has to remember where it stored the cached translations and what 68k code address each such chunk applies to.  In the compiled environment, this is handled by code in the compiler & linker, and done at build time rather than at runtime.

One thing to remember when discussing this topic (the PowerMac 68020 emulator) is that there were actually two emulators: The original table-based emulator that was released with the original NuBus-based PowerMacs, and the dynamic-recompilation (JIT) emulator that was released with the PCI-based PowerMacs. In fact, the latter also had the table-based emulator, and used it for interrupt-time emulation tasks!
All Motorola 68020 instructions are at least one 16-bit word, in many cases more but never less. And to be specific, that 16-bit word contains (almost) everything important about the instruction: Instructions are only ever longer when they need to pass parameters that won't fit in 16 bits, but that 16 bits can be considered "the" instruction.  So an emulator can be implemented as a table with 2^16 entries, which just gets and jumps to the function pointed to by the entry identified by an instruction interpreted as a 16-bit unsigned integer.
The trick with the PowerMac table-based emulator is that it isn't just a table of function pointers; that is, the system doesn't fetch an address from the table and then jump to that address. Instead, the table-based emulator has something like 4 32-bit PowerPC words per entry, and jumps directly to that entry directly to emulate each 68020 instruction. By being judicious in the mapping of 68020 state to PowerPC state (such as mapping specific 68020 registers to specific PowerPC registers), a great many 68020 instructions can be implemented entirely within the table entry including the return to the emulation loop. And for the 68020 instructions that can't be implemented by 4 PowerPC instructions, the table entry can just contain a PowerPC branch instruction that transfers control to the emulator's actual implementation of that instruction.
The downside of this implementation is that it can only ever be so fast. On the one hand, every 68020 instruction takes a specific amount of time to run based on its PowerPC implementation. On the other hand, that determinism allows, for example, device drivers to continue to be implemented in 68020 code rather than requiring all drivers to be updated. This is actually why the table-based emulator is still supported and used on PCI-based PowerMacs, even though the dynamic recompilation (JIT) emulator can often generate faster code.
One reason that the table-based emulator was used for drivers is that drivers are often "stacked." For example, the HFS filesystem calls Filesystem Manager, which calls the block device driver, which calls the SCSI Manager or ATA Manager or PCMCIA Manager etc., which calls a specific hardware device's driver. Furthermore transferring control between native PowerPC code (including drivers) and emulated 68020 code takes a lot of cycles. So if a so-called "mixed mode transition" needs to take place between those layers, it can actually wind up being a net negative to try to have only part of the driver stack in native PowerPC code when the code calling it or the code it calls is emulated 68020 code.
Another reason for the use of the table-based emulator for drivers is determinism: Because the dynamic-recompilation emulator may generate different code for different sequences of 68020 instructions, it's a lot harder to know exactly how long a specific sequence of 68020 instructions will take on any piece of hardware--especially when expanding L2 and L3 caches are taken into account. Since the table-driven emulator fits in L2 cache and uses a deterministic number of PowerPC instructions to emulate any given 68020 instruction, it's straightforward to continue to meet hardware timing requirements from 68020 code that runs under the table-driven emulator.
The trick to making this work is that the dynamic recompilation emulator isn't a replacement for the table-driven emulator but an enhancement of it. They share common state so that when (say) a 68020 application interacts with a 68020 device driver, even though there may be a switch from the dynamic-recompilation emulator to the table-driven emulator, there isn't a need to (expensively) transfer state between the two like there is when making a transition between PowerPC and 68020 code. They can use the same 68020/PowerPC register mappings, they can use the same data structures, and so on.

With 64k instructions, and 16 byte per instruction, the simulators need 1MByte of instruction cache. The first PowerPC macs didn’t have enough instruction cache, the second generation did for a massive speed gain. If many instructions can be emulated with instructions of the form a, b, c, X, Y, Z, jump to interpreter with the same three instructions X, Y, Z then we can store X, Y, Z, Jmp into 16 bytes and the interpreter for multiple instructions is a, b, c, Jmp XYZ sequence.

is it not basically threaded code (not subroutine threading, the real kind)?
